# PHP not detecting cookie set by Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

**EDIT: MY BAD, IT WAS A (SERVER SIDE) CACHING ISSUE. Thanks for the help.**

I have a site that when visited first checks for cookie "intro" and then if it doesn't exist, redirects it to an intro page.

```
<?php if (!isset($_COOKIE["intro"])) {
header( 'Location: http://explainasterisk.com/intro/' ) ; } ?>
```

When the user clicks the "begin" button on the intro page, the cookie is set using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $('.home').click(function () {
                  scroll(0, 0); //scrolltotop
                  var intro = "intro" //setting cookiename variable
                  var today = new Date();
                  var expire = new Date();
                  expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*365);
                  document.cookie = intro+"=1"
                                  + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();                  
                  $('.home').slideUp(3000, function () { //slideUp function 
                      //Nothing
                  });
              });
          });
</script>
```

In Opera and Chrome the cookie is being set, but when I click on the skip button on the intro page (that takes me back to the original page), I'm simply redirected to the Intro page. You can see this live here: http://explainasterisk.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!isset($_cookie["intro"])) {
```

is incorrect array name. It should be in CAPS, like this

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE["intro"])) {
```

Reference: [$_COOKIE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)

Thanks Brad Christie.

Comment: _Obligatory reference to [`$_COOKIE`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php)_

Answer (score 0):

The source of you problem is you don't have `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the beginning of your code (and  `ini_set('display_errors','On');` in development environment).

If you have it, PHP will display error message that there is no $_cookie variable.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give [jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) a try because it makes setting and handling cookies in javascript with expire dates so much easier.

One simple line:

```
$.cookie("[cooke name]", "[value]", { expires: [time in days]);
```

e.g.:

```
$.cookie("intro", "set", { expires: 365);
```

Your PHP snippet looks fine to me and - if the cookie is set correctly - should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the path and domain to the end of your cookie:

```
path=/; domain=.<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the cookie in javascript is being set with domain `.explainasterisk.com`

So try this before reading the cookie.

`ini_set("session.cookie_domain", ".explainasterisk.com");`